# recursion for fraction exercie (continued fraction problem with recursion) java programming

Tags: java

Hello i am having problem with understanding this recursive function.I was able to do same exercise when it was like from n to 1 but now i am confused and i dont know how to do it.I really need some help with code modification [picture of exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edd1R.png)

```
public static double razlomak(int a) {
      if(a>0) {
          return (a + 1/razlomak(a-1));
      }else { 
          return 1;
      }
  }
```

*I cant modify this code into exercise i sent i was trying but i failed every time*

Comment: You probably need a second parameter, to let you know when you've reached the end. Also, while we can infer what the exercise wants you to do, can you translate it and type it in here instead of linking an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this.  You can use a private helper method to convert to two arguments.

```
public static double razlomak(int a) {
    return _razlomak(a,a+1);
}
    
private static double _razlomak(int a, double q) {
     if(a > 0) {
         return _razlomak(a-1,a + 1/q);
     }
     return q;
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude,I missunderstood exercise and tried to do it with one vaiable which was impossible by the way.Thank you